# PHP session_start() hangs on Windows

Tags: php

I have a file here which is being run on a live site.
The session starts fine on my localhost running through XAMPP, but no longer works once pushed to my live server.

```
<?php
        session_start();
?>
```

That hangs up on session_start() on a Windows computer. On a Mac it works fine. What the heck is happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: is `set_ses_vars()` a custom function?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't affect the hanging. I have removed it, and it still hangs.

Comment: Make the shortest possible test case that causes the issue, and show all the code.

Comment: Also what do you mean Mac/Windows? You're viewing a website or running the code on the machine?

Comment: I have made the shortest possible code.. updated.

Comment: OK, so *just* `session_start();` will cause the issue? I mean, if you literally run just this code your (browser?) doesn't respond?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The page tries to load forever. Only on Windows though.

Comment: Any issue with the temporary folder? Any problem with the owning Windows user or server executable accessing the folder?

Comment: I have no idea if there is an issue with the temporary folder, that's why I'm here. It works fine when the website is loaded on a Mac, but does not when loaded on Windows.

Comment: So to clarify, the code (which is on the live server) hangs when you view it in a browser on a Windows machine, but not when you view it in a browser on a Mac? And if you remove `session_start()` it works fine?

Comment: is there any other heavy script using the session at the same time. Can you check your error logs for some possible errors/warnings?

Comment: Yes, Wesley. That is correct.

Comment: OK so which browsers are you testing on, and do you have any addons installed in those browsers? Have you tried other browsers on Windows?